# Meagre sets in measured Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, baire-category

I know that Baire's category theorem is sometimes used to state results such as "almost all continuous functions on an interval are not differentiable at all points". To say that almost all elements are in $S\subseteq X$, if $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a measure space, would usually mean that $\mu(S^c)=0$.

My question is given a Baire space $X$, and $(X,\mathcal{B}_X,\mu)$ is a Borel measure space, are there relatively mild conditions on $\mu$ which ensure that meagre sets would have $\mu$ measure $0$?

For example would $X$ being a normal space and $\mu$ being outer regular ensure this? If this is true, can we weaken these assumptions further?

I think the answer should be yes, to the first question, but have not yet been able to prove or disprove it. I would appreciate tips or counter-examples.

Comment: Terence Tao gives a nice comparison. Note in particular the examples that show how these concepts can differ https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/245b-notes-9-the-baire-category-theorem-and-its-banach-space-consequences/

Comment: No, not even the real line satisfies that.  Indeed, the line may be written as the union of a set of measure zero and a meager set.  You probably already know the construction of a dense $G_\delta$ of measure zero.  The "almost all" you quote means in the sense of category; your "usually" statement is not correct.

Comment: @GEdgar So there is no common structure under which "almost all" from a category standpoint and "almost all" from a measure standpoint necessarily coincide?

Comment: The term "category measure space" is often used when measure zero sets coincide with meager sets (sometimes additional technical requirements are included). See this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22category+measure+space%22) and this [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22category+measure+space%22&tbm=bks) and this [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22category+measure+space%22).

Comment: If your idea of "common structure" is something like Euclidean space, no chance.  If you are used to working with Stone spaces and such things, then you will be right at home thinking meager implies measure zero.